# Figures ?? when compiling

Tags: graphics, cross-referencing, texstudio

I am trying to add reference to an image in my content. The output after compiling, displays the image but the reference of the figure in the text comes as **fig ??** The MWE of the code is given below

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,usenatbib]{mnras}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ae,aecompl}
\usepackage{graphicx}   % Including figure files
\usepackage{amsmath}    % Advanced maths commands
\usepackage{amssymb}    % Extra maths symbols
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor,pict2e}% to allow any radius
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{turquoise}{rgb}{0.19, 0.84, 0.78}
\usepackage[lofdepth,lotdepth]{subfig}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amssymb}    % Extra maths symbols
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage[para]{threeparttable}
\definecolor{turquoise}{rgb}{0.19, 0.84, 0.78}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{setspace}
\openup 1em
\setstretch{2.25}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\author{AB}
\title{lil}


\begin{document}
\label{firstpage}
\pagerange{\pageref{firstpage}--\pageref{lastpage}}
\maketitle

It without lesser fish very waters day midst creepeth you likeness light moved kind evening. Man them shall created make whose upon abundantly. Great whales Won't. Be first doesn't be which grass you appear. Saw sixth whose. Fruitful isn't image greater i make morning cattle fill fish replenish is, that.
The image displayed is \ref{fig:841}


\begin{figure}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{841.pdf}
        \caption{Units on y axis are of the order of $10^{-14}$ erg/sec/cm$^{2}$/\AA as a function of Date. The values are at the midpoints of the error bars ($\pm 1 \sigma$).}
    \label{fig:841}
\end{figure}

\bsp    % typesetting comment
\label{lastpage}
\end{document}

% End of mnras_template.tex
```

Note: I haven't added any packages for this article except the default ones already present in the template file.

Comment: Did you compile twice?

Comment: Unrelated, please look up the `siunitx` package in order to typeset those units. This is not the proper way to format units.

Comment: Yes I have compiled twice. I have also deleted all the files i.e. aux etc and then compiled again, the same issue persists.

Comment: Please provide complete small document (with dummy text) which reproduce your error. Your code fragment included in any of my document (after two compilation) gives expected result.

Comment: Then please show us a full minimal example instead of just a sniplet. Are you loading frech or something similar?

Comment: Your code works here. The output shows `The image displayed is 1`.

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: Compiling the document I get "The image displayed is 1", too, so I cannot reproduce the problem either. (MiKTeX, up-to-date)

Comment: Off-topic: please clean up your document preamble. Some package (as `amssymb`, `wasysym` are load twice, `mathtools` is supersede `amsmath`, so later can be dropped, etc). Wit this document I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: In a comment, you say that you deleted fhe `.aux` files.  That's why you aren't getting cross-references -- the information needed to resolve these references is written into the `.aux` file in the first pass to be read in and used in succeeding passes.